What is this "extra padding" from the Entry widget from Tkinter?
Take this simple code:
import os
import tkinter as tk

root_window = tk.Tk()
root_window.geometry("200x200")

root_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root_window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

foo = tk.Canvas(root_window, bg="grey", width=10, height=10)
bar = tk.Canvas(root_window, bg="light grey", width=10, height=10)

foo.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

root_window.mainloop()

The resulting behavior is completely normal and expected:

but if you change foo to an Entry widget (and remove the sticky="nsew" from grid):
foo = tk.Entry(root_window, width=10) # same width
foo.grid(row=0, column=0)

Then the entry widget seems to get some sort of 'padding', on both sides, out of nowhere:

I thought that it had a default padx, but even after trying padx=(0,0), nothing happened.
It also only happens on its sides(left and right), top and bottom work normally.
Even if you use sticky="nsew" on the grid method, the result also has the extra space.
Is there something I am missing? Can I remove this "extra padding"?
PS: I tried using the syntax to make the images be on the post, instead of a link to them, but couldn't get it to work.

Having the same weight= means that you want to equally distribute excess space (beyond that required by the biggest widget) between the rows/columns - notice that the padding on the two sides of the Entry adds up to exactly the same width as the empty right column.  If you want the columns to have equal width, despite having unequal contents, you want to add uniform= to the .columnconfigure() calls.  (The value doesn't matter, it doesn't even need to be a number, it just needs to be the same for both.)

The width of Entry doesn't mean the total pixels that Entry widget will take on the root window. Instead, it means the total number of characters. So setting the width to 10 and if the average width of characters takes 10 pixels, it means the Entry widget will finally take 10 *10 = 100 pixels on the root window. Check this doc https://tkdocs.com/shipman/entry.html

The extra padding in the last image is not from the entry widget, but from the canvas widget on the right.  It can be removed by setting highlightthickness=0 when creating it:
bar = tk.Canvas(root_window, bg="light grey", width=10, height=10, highlightthickness=0)

Result:

